# how to deserialize this JSON using Newtonsoft.Json C#?

Tags: c#, json

how to deserialize this JSON using Newtonsoft.Json C#?

```
{
  "catalog": {
    "book": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "author": "Autho1",
        "title": "GDB",
        "genre": "Kl",
        "price": "15",
        "publish_date": "1999-09-02",
        "description": "desc about book"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "author": "Lil",
        "title": "JS",
        "genre": "DS",
        "price": "3.6",
        "publish_date": "1999-09-02",
        "description": "desc 2."
      }    
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to deserialize JSON into a structure, but in the end I have book = nil

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://json2csharp.com/

Comment: The frontpage of https://www.newtonsoft.com/json provides a great example to both serialize and deserialize.

Comment: Why structure? Class is a much better fit for these.

Comment: Step 1. make a class called `Book` with all the necessary properties. Step 2.  Make a class called `Catalog` with an array of `Book`, Step 3. Deserialize into type `Catalog`.

Comment: That's a flat, straight forward object. A simple special past in your favortie IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as documented at [official docs of Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) first of all for good code maintenance we should create a models that will describes all (or only needed to Domain/Buisness logic) data in C# class.
For your example this is Book class

```cs
[JsonProperty("book")]
    public class Book
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public uint ID {get; set;} //GUID is better but, check how it's will be parsed 
        [JsonProperty("author")]
        public string Author {get; set;} // string can be replaced by Author model
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title {get; set;}
        [JsonProperty("genre")]
        public string Genre {get; set;} // string can be replaced by Enum
        [JsonProperty("price")]
        public double Price {get; set;}
        [JsonProperty("publish_date")]
        public string PublishDate {get; set;} // string can be replaced DateTime
        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description {get; set;}
    }
```

And the catalog model

```cs
    public class Catalog
    {
        [JsonProperty("book")]
       public List<Book> Book {get; set;} = new List<Book>();
    }
```

After it you can do something kinda

```cs
string json = @"
{
  "catalog": {
    "book": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "author": "Autho1",
        "title": "GDB",
        "genre": "Kl",
        "price": "15",
        "publish_date": "1999-09-02",
        "description": "desc about book"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "author": "Lil",
        "title": "JS",
        "genre": "DS",
        "price": "3.6",
        "publish_date": "1999-09-02",
        "description": "desc 2."
      }    
    ]
  }
}";

Catalog catalog = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Catalog>(json);
```

There [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) attribute (somewhere not required) is used for saying default parser to name of field in json, if object is reqired and order (as I can remember that's all.

I hope that your trouble is solved, pls read doc in next time and be more patient in your researches.